# Nodejs, express & socket.io communicate between two static client pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

i am trying to build a remote for a gallery by using nodejs, express & socket.io.

the structure is as follows

```
/index.js
/public/screen.html
       /screen.js
       /remote.html
       /remote.js
```

the idea is to have a gallery of images displayed on `remote.html`, select one and send the selected index to `screen.html` by using socket.io.

as of now my code looks like this:

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(express.static('public'));

server.listen(8080, function(){
    // setup image gallery and stuff...
    connectToServer();
});
```

**remote.js**

```
var socket = null;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //some stuff
    connectToServer();
});
function showImage (index){  //called by events
    console.log('selected incdex: ' + index);
    if(socket != null) {
        socket.emit('selection', {id: index});
    };
}

function connectToServer(){

    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var text = document.querySelector('#name');
        socket.emit('newRemote', 'new remote connected');
        console.log('emitted welcome');

        socket.on('newScreen', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

**screen.js**

```
var socket = null;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //some stuff
    connectToServer();
});
function connectToServer(){
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var text = document.querySelector('#name');
        socket.emit('newScreen', { name: name });

        socket.on('newRemote', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
};
```

when starting with `node index.js` i get

```
listening on *:8080
```

and when loading screen or remote.html i get

```
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized MwtGFRCZamcyKkUpK5_W
```

as I see it: somehow a connection is established, but:

> no messages are sent / received on both ends
>   no logs are printed to the console for the connection events

any idea why nothing is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have mixed server-side code into your client. The 'connection' event is an event that needs to be listened to on the server, not your client files. Additionally, you cannot directly call client-side functions from your server-side code.
The below code does not work:

```
server.listen(8080, function(){
// setup image gallery and stuff...
connectToServer();
});
```

To achieve the above you will need to put the following code on your server:

```
server.listen(8080, function(){
  socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // setup image gallery and stuff...
    socket.emit('connectToServer', myPassedParameters);
  });
});
```

And the following listener for that event on the client:

```
socket.on('connectToServer', function (myPassedParameters) {
    var text = document.querySelector('#name');
      // stuff for client side here
    });
});
```

In addition to the above, you cannot do calls from one client file to another client file using socket.io. You would have to do a call to the server first and then call a function on the other file once it has been loaded for the user.